# How to make a chained object null-safe for iteration

Tags: java, loops, collections, nullpointerexception, java-8

New to Java.

I'm trying to avoid NullPointerException when iterating over a list. CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull() helps, but not for a chained object.

For example:

```
for (MyObject myObj : CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(
    result.item.getMyObject().getObjects())) {
    // do stuff
    }
```

I have no control over MyObject because I wrote a client that consumes this as a dependency. Any of these attributes could be null, and emptyIfNull() only protects against getObjects() returning null.

Is there a way to apply emptyIfNull() or something similar to the entire chain of calls?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you use the `Optional<MyObject>`?

Comment: Use `Optional`. And `Stream`. And **not** an ancient and outdated library - especially if you're new to Java!

Comment: maybe something like `for (MyObject myObj : Optional.ofNullable(result)
                              .map(e -> e.item)
                              .map(e -> e.getMyObject())
                              .map(e -> e.getObjects())
                              .orElse(Collections.emptyList())`